# Is it possible to generate pvk files with OpenSSL 3.0?

Tags: openssl, certificate, rsa, pem

Is it possible to create pvk files with OpenSSL 3.0?
In previous version, it could be done with this commands:

```
OPENSSL genrsa -out test.key -passout pass:blahblah 2048
OPENSSL rsa -in test.key -inform pem -out test.pvk -outform PVK -pvk-strong -passout pass:blahblah
```

But, when i run this commands in OpenSSL 3.0, second command gives me an error:

```
300F0000:error:07880106:common libcrypto routines:ossl_pw_get_passphrase:reason(524550):crypto\passphrase.c:265:No password method specified
300F0000:error:04800068:PEM routines:i2b_PVK:bad password read:..\crypto\pem\pvkfmt.c:1058
```

I loaded legacy provider, but unfortunately, no effect.
Do you have any suggestions or workarounds of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in the implementation of 3.0.

It is fixed by this branch: https://github.com/t8m/openssl/tree/fix-pvk-encoder
see also https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/17181

Answer (score 0):

The error 'No password method specified' is referring to the fact that test.key has a password and you haven't entered it

you need to either;

1. not set a password on test.key (using -nodes in the first command)
   or
2. in the second command use -passin pass: ... etc (or env:,stdin:,etc)

Comment: Unfortunately, option passin does not help me( I think this is not about password in test.key, this is about pvk encryption, because second command works if i use option -pvk-none instead of -pvk-strong